# 208v Three phase No Neutral

Tags: power-supply

I'm currently looking at a new application and found out the customer has no neutral but has a three phase 208v supply, Is there any possibility or any suggestion of how I can get a Neutral?

Comment: why do you need neutral? What load you want to connect on it? Industrial things have usually no neutral, the control voltage is get with a transformer, but this is small power.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a transformer - it will have a delta connection on the non-neutral primary side and a star (wye) connection on the secondary side.

Such things are common in control panels on continental European kit.

Here's a European transformer which is the kind of thing I mean:

http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/din-rail-panel-mount-transformers/4197423/

Comment: Ok Great I can look into this, Would the secondary side still be 208v Three Phase just with a neutral?

Comment: In principle you could have what you wanted, if you can find a transformer which does it.  In general people turn the 3ph supply back into the 1ph supply that's common in the same locality.  So I guess that would be 208V line-line and 120V line-neutral (1ph) for you.

Comment: Yes that's true, Think the single phase supply would be a better option for me as 120v is all i need to run my components. Thanks for the assistants.